# {"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','start_clean.boot'}} init terminating in do_boot ({cannot get bootfile,start_clean.boot})

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, erlang

when I run command rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management in windows 10. I got below error

{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','start_clean.boot'}}
init terminating in do_boot ({cannot get bootfile,start_clean.boot})

. I have windows 10.
. ERLANG is installed and ERLANG_HOME varaible is set

Please help me in resolving this

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue and solved it by reinstalling it. Steps I followed on Windows 10:

1. Uninstall RabbitMQ
2. Delete the folder `%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ`
3. Delete folder RabbitMQ Server from `C:\ProgramFiles`
4. set `ERLANG_HOME`
5. Reinstall RabbitMQ via administrator account

Assuming you installed ERLANG via administrator account as well. If not then first reinstall Erlang before reinstalling RabbitMQ.

Comment: %APPDATA% on win10 takes you to the path till Roaming  -
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that I was installing the latest (version 23) of `ERLANG`... which has the `bin` folder one level deeper and that caused issues for `RabbitMQ`... even if I set the `ERLANG_HOME` environment variable that one level deeper.

What worked was installing the latest of version `22` (`22.3` at the time of this post) of `ERLANG`.

Answer (score 0):

why？：

1.when you specify the installation path and do not follow the default path

2.the installer will create a `C:Program Files\rabbitmq_server-3.11.1\Rabbit MQ\plugins` folder,the path you specified will be missing these files

solve：

merge the files in `C:Program Files\Rabbit MQ\rabbitmq_server-3.11.1\plugins` into the directory you specify，like`D:\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.11.1\plugins`